# How to solve "Too long with no output (exceeded 10m0s): context deadline exceeded" in CircleCI?

Tags: continuous-integration, circleci

[CirleCI Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFkLB.png)

As you see in the image all tests are successful but it continues until it reaches 10Min without an output. After that CircleCI take this as a failure to the test.

I expected CircleCI to stop once the tests are completed.

Comment: In general it means your tests are waiting for inputs: you need to put option to prevent this. Most common is --quiet but please display your `config.yaml` file for a better help.